# Handling multiple checkbox array in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I am going to build a survey form generator. `name` attribute in form are dynamic that comes from database. So I don't know the `name` of any input element. From database, I had generated the form and its working but I have problem with submitting multiple checkbox value and store into database.

I tried :

**View**

```
 // $inputtype, $name comes from database.
<input type="$inputtype" name="$name"[]>
 // I can fetch values of all checked option and loop through it and convert it into string using explode and insert into database. Thats not a big deal.
```

But, the problem is as `name` attribute is dynamic from database. I don't know `name` attr in runtime. So I can't do `$this->input->post("checkbox_name");`. So, I directly inserted form data into database by creating database fields that are required for forms in runtime. And insert form data by doing :

```
 $this->input->post();   //directly to model.
```

But, when I tried to insert multiple checkbox array same way, It throws error `Array to string conversion` in `mysql/mysql_driver.php` of codeigniter library. How can I overcome with this problem. Please Help.

**Update**

Array I get after form submission from `$this->input->post()`

```
 array
'first_name' => string 'sushil ' (length=7)
'last_name' => string 'shrestha' (length=8)
'gen' => string 'Male' (length=4)
'hobbies' => 
  array
    0 => string 'gaming' (length=6)
    1 => string 'football' (length=8)
    2 => string 'cricket' (length=7)
'language' => string 'IOS' (length=3)
```

But I cannot store array of hobbies directly to database.

Comment: Try as `$postdata = $this->input->post(); print_r($postdata);`

Comment: This gives me array of all the form data with key value pair. In case multiple checkbox It makes another child array inside form data array.

Comment: Then post that array and here you'll get the name attr of your `checkbox`

Comment: Its dynamic from database so I can't know which is checkbox in runtime. So I can't do so.

Comment: Post the array that you were getting within your `$postdata` variable

Comment: @Uchiha I had updated my question.

Comment: you can use `json_encode` to save your array data in db.

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to store hobbies like this way, you should always use separate table with Foreign key relate with your user table. Means your hobbie table contains user's hobbies. i.e use user id, tbl_hobbies.id